# C# implementation of concave hull / alpha shapes

Tags: c#, geometry, algorithm, concave-hull

I'm looking for a C# implementation of the Concave hull (alpha shapes) algorithm.
I already found several Java, Python and C++ implementation but no C# version.
The other implementation are quite complicated and will take a lot of time to convert so I'm looking for a C# version which is already working.

I'm already using NetTopologySuite and can do a delaunay triangulation. This will produce a convex hull, which I don't need. 
Something like this is what I need: http://www.geosensor.net/phpws/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=13

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is unlikely anyone would implement such a complex algorithm in C#. It may be easier to use a C++ version and then import the results into your C# code somehow.

Comment: It's hard to believe that porting math code in Java to C# would be all that difficult.

Comment: @vince, that is how I originally learnt c#! Excluding 3rd party libs, I thought it easy.  Paul: Euclidean space, or on the Earth's surface? I'm going to be coding up the latter before the end of the year...

Comment: Did you try: [ConcaveHullGenerator](https://github.com/Liagson/ConcaveHullGenerator)?

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to implement this algorithm in C#? Could you share your code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same situation as you, in need for such an algorithm in C#.

The only useful thing I found so far was this [research document from Uppsala Universitet from Sweden](http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/projektTDB/ht13/project10/Project-10-report.pdf) which provides a pretty neat pseudo code with details and explanations that I will try to follow in order to implement it in C#.

Maybe you'll be able to implement it faster than me, if not, I'll share it.

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to implement this algorithm in C#? Could you share your code? Thank you.